# Type Parameters and Algebraic Data Type?

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
scala> sealed trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case object Boy extends Parent
defined object Boy

scala> case object Girl extends Parent
defined object Girl
```

And then a method:

```
scala> def foo[A <: Parent](x: Parent): A = {
     |    if(true) Boy else Girl
     | }
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boy.type
 required: A
          if(true) Boy else Girl
                   ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Girl.type
 required: A
          if(true) Boy else Girl
                            ^
```

At compile-time, is it not known that `Boy` and `Girl` are the only sub-classes of `Parent, i.e. A`?

Comment: `foo` cannot return an `A` since that is chosen by the client, the most specific type it returns is `Parent`. What would you expect `foo[Girl]` to do?

Comment: "of `Parent`, i.e. `A`" - this is where your logic went wrong. `Parent` is *not* `A`. It's a supertype of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```scala
def foo[S >: Parent](p:Parent):S = if(true) Boy else Girl
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe defining the method with `A >: Parent` instead of `A <: Parent` shows more clearly what's wrong with your code:

```
scala> def foo[A >: Parent](x: Parent): A = { if(true) Boy else Girl }
foo: [A >: Parent](x: Parent)A

scala> foo[Parent](Boy)
res1: Parent = Boy

scala> foo[Object](Boy)
res2: Object = Boy
```

I.e. `res2` is an `Object` whereas `res1` is a `Parent`.

Like Lee mentioned in the comments, in your code you'd expect it to be called with `A` being `Girl.type` so the signature would then become: `foo[Girl.type](x: Parent): Girl.type` but the return type of your implementation is not `Girl.type`.

Here's a variant of your code using `A <: Parent` that does work:

```
scala> def foo[A <: Parent](x: A): A = x 
foo: [A <: Parent](x: A)A

scala> foo[Boy.type](Boy)
res3: Boy.type = Boy
```